# C++ shared objects

Tags: c++, object, shared

I have got four classes `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.

- Class `A` has a member `b` of class
  `B`.
- Class `B` has a member `c` of class `C`.

`A` has a member `D* dpointer;`

This hierarchy has to be preserved (in fact this is a GUI with app, window, panel as `A`, `B` and `C`).

Now B and C must use a method from `*dpointer`.

Is there something more elegant than giving `dpointer` as a member of `B` and `C` ? Is it bad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation you should probably pass a reference to `B` and `C` instead of a pointer. As @Billy ONeil says in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714361/c-shared-objets/2714378#2714378), you should use a [`shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) or a [`scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) if possible and appropriate (cannot judge without knowing more about `D` and `dpointer`) in `A`.
Passing a reference to `B` and `C` has the advantage of making clear that these two merely use
the `D`-object, but do not control it's lifecycle, and that an instance of `D` is required to use these classes (with a pointer `NULL` would be an option). If `B` and `C` only call `const` methods on `D`, you can even pass a const reference.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you could put D inside of a `shared_ptr<D>`, which would alleviate any memory management headaches you might possibly have.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct D;
struct CommonABC
{
   CommonABC(D * & dpointer) : dpointer(dpointer) {}
   D * & dpointer;
};
struct C : CommonABC 
{
   C (const CommonABC & common) : CommonABC(сommon) {}
};
struct B: CommonABC 
{
   B (const CommonABC & common) : CommonABC(сommon), c(common) {}
   C c;
};
struct A 
{
   A () : b(CommonABC(dpointer)) {}
   D * dpointer;
   B b;
};
```

Comment: Why the references to pointers? Why not just store the pointer directly?

Comment: Because you can change `dpointer` in `struct A` and get changed value in `B` and `C`.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, I would probably opt for the shared_ptr solution mentioned above. But here is another way that is not often covered in the C++ literature, of the sort you might find in an interview question or a BrainBench test:

```
struct D{
  D(int val);
  void foo();
};
struct C:private virtual D{
  void bar(){
    foo();
  } 
};
struct B:private C,private virtual D{
  void car(){
    foo();
  }
};

struct A:private B,private virtual D{   
   A(int val):D(val){}
   void aar(){
    car();
    foo();
   }

};
```

private inheritance implements the has-a relationship, just like making it a member. The only difference is that you can only have one of each type. In this case the same D object is shared by all classes in the composition.

But if you want others to be able to understand what you are doing, go with the shared_ptrs.